# Изменение типа данных при ajax запросе

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, javascript

День добрый!
Заметил такую неприятную вещь при ajax запросе. Используется jQuery + jQueryMobile.
На картинке показаны отправляемые и получаемые данные, id был числом, стал строкой.
Кто-нибудь сталкивался?

[image]

Comment: Поясню, что вложенность массивов большая и вручную менять тип не вариант.

Comment: .

    is_numeric('11779'); // true, в чем проблема?

Comment: AlexWindHope, см. коммент выше

PS, is_numeric проверяет переменную на число

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А чего вы ожидали?) При post запросе все равно все кодируется в url-вид

```
...
Content-Length: N;

email[0][email]=awegfawef&email[0][id]=11779&somevar=somevalue
...
```

А php парсит то что приходит в `$_POST`. А в `$_POST` все - либо массив, либо строка.

Просто при использовании приводите к int

```
$id = (int) $_POST['email'][0]['id'];
```

Comment: Действительно, проверил на другом хостинге. Раньше это небыло важно, поэтому не замечал.